# Image animation in CSS dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, image, animation, menu

I have a dropdown menu that has images in the first level, then text. When the user mouseover the image it transforms slightly into a trapezoid (rotateY) and drops a menu. But when the user moves the mouse to the menu the image goes back to a square. I would like it to stay a trapezoid until the user moves the mouse away from the image AND the menu. Any help would be appreciated, preferably with only CSS+HTML, as I have been suffering with this for  long time.

Tian

Comment: Please add your code... I guess you can delegate the :hover to the parent but all depends of your structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you meant skewY. I agree with Danko's comment that adding `:hover` to the main menu item.

Here's a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4cWpF/4/)**

Use this (or similar) markup for your menu item with the sub-menu:

```
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/40/"></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

With this css for your top-level menu item:

```
.menu-item:hover > a {
    -webkit-transform: skewY(10deg);
    transform: skewY(30deg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! No, I do use rotateY inside another div, but yes, your solution works.